# convert Javascript button to VF page button

Tags: visualforce

I have written a Javascript page to assign a record type to a record. But the javascript button will not work on salesforce1. I want to convert that to a vf page button. Kindly help me.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var oppObj = new sforce.SObject("Custom_Object__C"); 
oppObj.Id = '{!Custom_Object__C.Id}'; 
oppObj.RecordTypeId = '012F000000XXXXXXX'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([oppObj]); 

if (result[0].success=='false') { 
alert(result[0].errors.message); 
} else { 
var r = confirm('Please note\n After you click the Submit Survey Button, You cannot edit this record\n Press OK to proceed and cancel to go back to previous page'); 
if(r == true){ 
location.reload(true); 
} 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by VF page button. do you want to use this in VF page.

Comment: @tushar-- yes. Just like how we give on click javascript, i want to use vf page. So i wanna implement the same functionality using vf page. So how can I write

Comment: In other words-- rewrite this JavaScript button to vf page button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
 <script src="/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js"></script >
    <script>
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
function execute()
{
    var oppObj = new sforce.SObject("Custom_Object__C"); 
    oppObj.Id = '{!Custom_Object__C.Id}'; 
    oppObj.RecordTypeId = '012F000000XXXXXXX'; 
    var result = sforce.connection.update([oppObj]); 

    if (result[0].success=='false') { 
    alert(result[0].errors.message); 
    } else { 
    var r = confirm('Please note\n After you click the Submit Survey Button, You cannot edit this record\n Press OK to proceed and cancel to go back to previous page'); 
    if(r == true){ 
    location.reload(true); 
    } 
    }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="execute();"/>
<apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Comment: so the new button content should be selected as "visualforce page" ?

Comment: A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

Unexpected token <

Comment: Ratan-- i selected new custom button. If I select the content as vf page, I am unable to get a space to paste the code. Kindly let me know the steps please. I apologize as I am new to salesforce

Comment: Not sure where to paste the code. If I select vf page content, the space to paste the code just vanishes

Comment: Its the same code what you provided. I just added my custom object name

Comment: Kindly tell me how did you want me to proceed. I mean I will create a new button. Name it. Select detail list view. Display with sidebar. And next?

Comment: Just now i have tested this code in my org, working fine.

Comment: What did you select in "content type"?

Comment: Thank you so much @Ratan for patiently helping me out and fixing the issue. Updated code is as below

Comment: @user3303348 Most welcome

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use this in VF page there are multiple approach which you can use. For example one approach is

Create command button in VF page.

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Update Value" action="{!updateValue}" rerender="msg" />
```

Controller

```
public void updateValue() {
    Opportunity opp = [Select Id, Record from Opportunity WHERE ID =: oppId] //variable store oppId
 //else if you have already opportunity variable then don't query them again use old variable
opp.RecordTypeId = '012F000000XXXXXXX'; 
try {
    update opp;
    //display successfully update page message
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Record update successfully'));
} catch(Exception ex) {
     // display error message
     ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,ex.getmessage()));
}

}
```

Also as a **Good Practices Don't Hardcoded the Id in code use custom setting instead.**

Comment: Thank you so much. you are right. I shall use the custom setting. I appreciate your help and suggestion