# Replacing a JS button with a lightning component (or whichever the best solution might be)

Tags: javascript, lightning

Good afternoon,
I understand this may seem like a duplicate question but I believe it is not. Please enlighten me since I'm new to lightning. I'm trying to get my JS buttons to work in lightning without much success.
The first approach I tried was by creating a lightning component. It works perfectly except for the fact that instead of having the button on the top right it appears in the Feed area.
Code for this solution:
Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" controller="ApexController">
<!-- Attribute -->
<aura:attribute name="loading" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<!-- Event handlers -->
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.myAction}" value="{!this}" />
<!-- Lightning design system "spinner" + loading message -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.loading}">
<div class="slds-spinner_container">
<div class="slds-spinner slds-spinner-brand slds-spinner-medium" role="status">
<div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
<div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
</div>
</div>
</aura:if>
<!-- /Spinner -->
</aura:component>
```

Js Controller

```
({
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
var action = component.get("c.assignToCurrentUser"); // method on ApexController.cls
// v.recordId does not have to be explicitly defined as an attribute.
// this is taken care of the force:hasRecordId implementation
var params = {"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")};
action.setParams(params);
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
var state = response.getState();
component.set("v.loading", false);
if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
{
console.log(response.getReturnValue());
helper.helperMethod("success", "Case assignment", "Case has been assigned to you!");
$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
}
else
{
// Show "toast" -> nice message dialog
helper.helperMethod("error", "Case assignment", "The system was unable to assign the case to you. Please contact your salesforce administrator");
}
// automatically close dialog -> so no user action needed
$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Js Helper

```
({
helperMethod : function(toasttype, title, message, data) {
data = data || [];
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams({
type: toasttype,
mode: "sticky",
title: title,
message: message,
messageTemplate: message,
messageTemplateData: data
});
toastEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Apex controller

```
public class ApexController {
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean assignToCurrentUser(Id recordId)
{
    Case caseObj=new Case();
    caseObj.Id = recordId; 
    caseObj.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    update caseObj;
    return true;
}
}
```

In Case > Buttons, Links and actions > click New Action
Action Type: Lightning component
Lightning Component: The one created above
After it is created add it to the page layout in the salesforce 1 and lightning area

The second solution looks like the one I've seen in 
[convert Javascript button to VF page button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101733/convert-javascript-button-to-vf-page-button) but my top priority was to get it to work with lightning components instead

Comment: I guess when you use a Visualforce page using lightning out to expose a component, [toast doesn't work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158283/lightning-toast-is-not-working).

Comment: It does work. The problem with the visualforce page with the lightning component in it is the refresh. I mentioned the toasts for the second solution, which does not use the lightning components, it is just a visualforce page with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the button is appearing in the feed area instead of the top right actions is related to the fact that this quick action was created for a case. It looks fine for leads, for example. This means the first solution works according to the specifications and is a valid one.
I'll change the component to show a button and add it anywhere I like in the record page instead.